# Java @PathParam always null

Tags: java, rest, jersey, path-parameter

I'm trying to use the @PathParam using Jersey, but it always sees it as null.

Here's the method:
The url is `http://localhost:8080/GiftRegistryAPI/api/v2/inventory/david` with `/v2/inventory` being at the class level

```
package com.omar.rest.inventory;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;

import com.omar.rest.util.*;

@Path("/v2/inventory")
public class V2_Inventory {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response returnHostRegistries(@QueryParam("hostId") int hostId) throws Exception {

    String returnString = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    try {
        // A host ID of 0 indicates a null parameter, there will never be a host with an ID of 0
        if (hostId == 0) { 
            return Response.status(400).entity("Error: please provide a valid host ID for this search").build();
        }

        Schema dao = new Schema();
        jsonArray = dao.qryReturnHostRegistries(hostId);

        returnString = jsonArray.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able to process your request").build();
    }
    System.out.println(returnString);

    return Response.ok(returnString).build();

}

@Path("/{firstName}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response returnSearchedRegistries(@PathParam("firstName") String name) throws Exception{

    String returnString = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    System.out.println("Name: " +name);
    try {
        Schema dao = new Schema();
        jsonArray = dao.qryReturnHostRegistries(name);

        returnString = jsonArray.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able to process your request").build();
    }

    System.out.println(returnString);

    return Response.ok(returnString).build();
}
```

}

The `name` parameter when debugged is always null, and I can't find any way at all of getting it to recognise I've entered anything in.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: can you put all class? its impossible to guess when the root address is not there

Comment: It was only when I copied it into the post above I noticed an incorrect import statement. Changed the import statement and it works

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was my import statement

```
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
```

should have been

```
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this error, most of the time the issue is wrong import. Just make sure you have `import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;`